# Erro de tipo de variável não declarada no construtor de classe

Tags: javascript, typescript, classes, interface

Estou criando uma classe de `ErrorHandler` para uma API. Quando vou criar as variáveis no construtor da classe, o TypeScript acusa que a varável `statusCode` não possui tipo definido:

```
interface ErrorObj {
  statusCode: number;
  message: string;
}

class ErrorHandler extends Error {
  constructor({ statusCode, message }: ErrorObj) {
    super();
    this.statusCode = statusCode; // variável que o TypeScript acusa erro de tipo
    this.message = message;
  }
}
```

Recebo este erro:

> ```
> Property 'statusCode' does not exist on type 'ErrorHandler'. ts(2339)
> ```

Essa tipagem não viria da interface?

Comment: Olá Matheus, apesar da resposta do Luiz explicar bem aonde foi a falha, fechei a pergunta porque é um simples erro de uso/digitação (não falo de erro de parser) que realmente é muito eventual de ocorrer e se traduzir a "mensagem de erro" já ajudaria a entender o problema facilmente. Mais detalhes: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic - Obrigado por compreender, e seja bem vindo ao site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perceba que a classe `ErrorHandler` extende `Error` (e portanto deve seguir o contrato estipulado por `Error`).

No entanto, não define nenhuma propriedade `statusCode` explicitamente, de modo que o tipo para `statusCode` *não* existe na definição da classe `ErrorHandler`.

É por isso que definir `message` não acusa erro. A propriedade `message` já é [definida na classe `Error`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L974), de modo que sua declaração, embora presente, seja implícita.

Portanto, você deve *declarar* a propriedade e seu tipo na classe:

```
interface ErrorObj {
  statusCode: number;
  message: string;
}

class ErrorHandler extends Error {
  // Declarando a propriedade `statusCode`:
  statusCode: number;

  constructor({ statusCode, message }: ErrorObj) {
    super();
    this.statusCode = statusCode;
    this.message = message;
  }
}
```

---

É importante ter em mente que o tipo da classe é diferente do tipo de um dos parâmetros do construtor. Perceba que a interface `ErrorObj` está definindo o tipo do *primeiro* parâmetro do construtor, mas não da classe em si.

Por causa disso, o tipo da interface em nada reflete na assinatura de tipos da classe.

Comment: Quem deu negativo poderia explicar o motivo, por favor?